# how to Increament date daywise

Tags: php

i have in my database records based on team types.now i need the system to show records of entire team from database based on dates entered i.e if i enter 06-June-2012 to 16-june-2012 it should show me all records from first date to other date. (in php)

```
$sql="SELECT mstEmp.empname,InDate, dailyattendance.InTime,dailyattendance.OutTime,mstEmp.teamtype FROM mstEmp left join dailyattendance on (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname) where (InDate between '$from' AND '$to') and mstEmp.teamtype='$chk' GROUP BY mstEmp.empname";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {           
  list($name,$indate,$in,$out,$t) = $row;
  if($row[1]==NULL ||$row[2]==NULL || $row[3]==NULL) { 
    $row[3]='NULL' ;
    $row[2]='NULL' ;
  } else {
    $row[2] = date("g:i A", $in);
    $row[3]= date("g:i A" ,$out);
  }
  $d3 = date("d-m-Y (D)", $in);
  $bg = '';
  if(date('D', $in) == 'Sun' || date('D', $in) == 'Sat')
    $bg = 'bgcolor=#EEEEEE';

  echo "<tr $bg><td colspan=4>Date: ".$d3."</td></tr>";
  if($indate != $date) {
    $date = $indate;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=left width='35%'>".trim($name)."</td>";
    echo "<td align=center width='20%' >".$row[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td align=center  width='23%' >".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "<td align=center width='16%'>".$t."</td>";
    //echo "</tr></table><br>";
  }
}
echo "</tr></table><br>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need; can you articulate what your code is supposed to do, and what it is currently doing? It may also help to see the query you are running, some sample data, and example of the output you *want* with the given data.

Comment: Description suggests stuff completely different from subject, and code does not suggest anything ;) In fact the code does irrelevant comparisons on variables to assign new values it never even uses later on

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date (string), and you want to add N days to it:

```
$date = date($format, strtotime($date, "+{$N}day"));
```

If you want to calculate date N days from now:

```
$date = date($format, time() + $N*86400); // 86400 is number of seconds in 1 day
```

---

If, on the other hand (and thats what it looks like from your question really...) you're looking to filter results based on a date range, then you have two options:

1. Filter the results in `SQL` (before php) - `WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'`
   I would strongly suggest to stick with this option, because if your table is going to have a lot of records, filtering results in php will be cpu and memory consuming.
2. You can convert both dates to seconds first - `$time1 = strtotime($date1)` (and same for the second date, and then every time you need to compare to the range, convert the date you need to compare as well, and just check if the resulting integer is between the two you calculated earlier.

---

If you have two date ranges (one in input - `$from` and `$to`) and one in database (`InDate` and `OutDate` columns), then to get the records where these ranges cross you can do this:

```
`WHERE InDate >= '$to' AND OutDate <= '$from'`
```

---

If you just want to loop (in php) from `$dateA` to `$dateB`, then you can do this:

```
// strtotime() converts date to number of seconds since Jan 1 1970
// 86400 is number of seconds in a day, so it ensures steps of 1 day
for($time=strtotime($dateA); $time<=strtotime($dateB); $time+=86400) {
}
```

Comment: $sql="SELECT mstEmp.empname,InDate, dailyattendance.InTime,dailyattendance.OutTime,mstEmp.teamtype FROM mstEmp left join dailyattendance on (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname) where (InDate between '$from' AND '$to') and mstEmp.teamtype='$chk' GROUP BY  mstEmp.empname";

Comment: So, you already have only records where `InDate` in range between `$from` and `$to`...

Comment: your loop is working on `rows` from mysql, not on `dates`... `InDate` and `OutDate` are parts of the result row (each row may have different set of dates). What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: there is a team of employees and want to see entire teams inout time from indate to outdate.

Comment: So, let me get this straight... your input is `$from` and `$to`? And you want to show all records where `InDate-OutDate` date range and `$from-$to` date range have common days?

Comment: `WHERE InDate>='$to' AND OutDate<='$from'`

Comment: i m able to increament date but unable to show the team on one day ...i.e one team person is shown on 1 adte and the other is shown on next day..

Comment: not really... :( maybe give sample data (a few rows) that you have in database, and what/how you want to display in the end?

Comment: You can add it to the question (data does not have to be real, you know...).. this way the question and answer will be more helpful for others

Comment: Date: 15-july-2012

HolderName | InTime | OutTime | TeamType

Afsgh    | 9.30   | 5.30    | HR
fdsgdf     | 9.30   | 6.30    | HR

Date: 16-july-2012

HolderName | InTime | OutTime | TeamType

Afsgh    | 10.30   | 5.30    | HR
fdsgdf     | 9.30    | 6.30    | HR
this is what i want

Comment: I think you need to `ORDER BY InDate`, because `GROUP BY` clause automatically applies order by that column (and then you get results listed not in order you shown here)

Comment: single employee entry for those days is being shown but i want entitre team details

Comment: what is "entire team details" ?

Comment: i found this code working correctly :  if ($ddate != $row[1])